# h1 - h6 responsive font-size

Tags: html, css, font-size

How can I change my h1-h6 font-size for every single @query sizes?
I have a simple code like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="katartica.com/wp-content/themes/katartika/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css"> 
body {
    font-size: 100%;
}
@media (max-width:768px){
    body, h1, h2 {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}
@media (min-width:768px){
    body, h1, h2 {
        font-size: 3em;
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>questoèuntestomoltolungo</h1>
    <h2>questoèuntestomoltolungo</h2>
    questo è il body
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to do it h1 and h2 change its sizes for every querys, but they have the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `media queries` are in conflict.. you can't have a `max-width` and `min-width` with same size, therefore it will only choose one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The "H" tags are handled with em therefore by using the same "em" these are equalized.

The W3C recommends using these styles as the default:

```
    h1 { font-size: 2em; }
    h2 { font-size: 1.5em; }
    h3 { font-size: 1.17em; }
    h4 { font-size: 1.12em; }
    h5 { font-size: .83em; }
    h6 { font-size: .75em; }
```

If you want to enlarge them all you should do with each one.

Here you have a complete User Agent stylesheet defaults [Here](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues to answer your question:

1. media queries should not overlap exactly so something like this would be better:

[image]

2. the reason your size of h1 and h2 are the same is because you are setting them to be the same size when you do this:

   `body, h1, h2 {font-size: 3em;}`

You need to do them separately like so:

```
body { font-size: 1em; }
h1 { font-size: 2rem; }
h2 { font-size: 3em; }`
```

and you would have to do that for each media query.

Putting it all together you could do this:

[image: screenshot of media queries code]